# SEO rel="nofollow" helps avoid duplicate content?

Tags: search, seo, search-engine

I am importing a series of XML feeds from another website for content mash-up purposes.  The content is includes the Title and first few paragraphs of the article and links back to the original website.  My concern is that Google could count this as duplicate content and affect my page ranking?  I was told to insert rel="nofollow" in the link back to the original article and that would help?  Can anyone provide a more detailed explanation of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, rel="nofollow" is nice way to tell google that you don't want google to pass link juice to another site through that particular link or page. For detailed explanation I would suggest you to follow this..

[google nofollow guidelines](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96569)

And for your duplicate content issue, you don't have to worry about that too much. It is not considered duplicate content as long as you are not just copying and pasting the whole articles in your page. Just keep them up to the titles and a little excerpt and a link to the original.